# Is it legal to record your room mates, without their permission or knowledge in "community areas"?

Tags: criminal-law, washington

UNITED STATES: WASHINGTON STATE: PIERCE COUNTY: TACOMA CITY

hey guys, i have a question, i understand that the law right now is that you cannot legally record a phone call in Washington state without first giving notice to the other party, my question, is Is it legal to record your room mates, without their permission or knowledge in "community areas"

i'm not talking if they invite you into their private rooms can you record them without their knowledge or consent.

i am talking about community areas, public spaces in the house, the kitchen, the hallways, the transitionary spaces, things like that.

thank you.

Comment: Are you suspecting them of committing some kind of crime?

Comment: Are you asking about audio recording, video recording, or both? I think you're asking about audio only, but it's probably worth clarifying.

Comment: both audio and video

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Would pure video work?

Comment: threats, threats of violence, domestic violence incidents, people accusing other people of stealing stuff, things of that nature, i don't think they have any reasonable expectation of privacy because there is no privacy in common areas, any one can just walk, and they do, the department of corrections comes every now and then, my goal is to record a domestic violence incident should it occur.

Comment: This is getting extremely fact-specific, to the point that you really need legal advice.  If you're seeking to help a victim of domestic violence, a local domestic violence shelter may be able to connect you with a lawyer who could help.  Random strangers on the internet aren't going to be able to assess the facts in enough detail here to be able to advise you accurately.

Comment: Basically, what you're trying to do is at the very least _extremely close_ to committing a crime, and even if it ultimately ends up being on the "not a crime" side of that line, that may only come to light after a long, expensive, and painful court battle.

Comment: Given what you're trying to record, there is one relevant exception: [Threats of bodily harm may be recorded without prior consent](https://www.kiro7.com/news/local/state-supreme-court-victims-can-record-conversations-without-prior-consent/652343502/).  But you'd have to somehow _only_ record the threats.  And again, you really want legal advice on how to do this without breaking the law.

Answer (score 0):

### No, not without consent

RCW 9.73.030 states, in relevant part:

> it shall be unlawful for any individual...to intercept, or record any...[p]rivate conversation, by any device electronic or otherwise designed to record or transmit such conversation regardless how the device is powered or actuated without first obtaining the consent of all the persons engaged in the conversation.

Someone having a conversation in their own home with no one else around would expect that conversation to be private, so claiming it's a "public space" within the home is unlikely to go anywhere.

Separately, recording people in their home without their knowledge or consent is just a really bad idea for a whole variety of non-legal reasons.

Comment: so, the home is not private, their rooms are private, the rest of the home is public community areas, i can bring anyone into the house in the community areas and they can't stop me, they can do the same,

Comment: It's still private, in that there aren't more than a handful of people (the people who live in the house & their guests) who are allowed in. It's also generally about expectations of privacy: you wouldn't expect someone to listen in on a conversation an empty room in your own home, even if you're not the only person who lives there. See, e.g., [Katz v. United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katz_v._United_States), in which a person was held to have a reasonable expectation of privacy in a conversation in a public phone booth. That's in the 4th Amendment context, but it's similar.

Comment: really, the home is not private, animals, junkies, any guy can just walk in, police, department of corrections, i have no say what so ever who can come in, anyone can because i can't prove if they are a guest or not, only the rooms and bathrooms are private,